# Discord JS Bot, Editing Permissions

Tags: javascript, discord, permissions, discord.js, roles

I am trying to create a slash command, and I don't really understand how you can edit permission based on a string input, for an example if a person enters "SEND_MESSAGES" with a role and true bool, Currently testing with the defined_permission

Script:

```
const role = interaction.options.getRole('role');
const defined_permission = interaction.options.getString('defined-permission');
const custom_permission = interaction.options.getString('custom-permission');
const enabled = interaction.options.getBoolean('enabled');

console.log(` > DEBUG | ${defined_permission}`)

if (!enabled) {
    interaction.reply("You are required to put a true or a false on if it should added or removed.");
    return
}

if (!role) {
    interaction.reply("You are required to define a role")
    return
}

if (!defined_permission && custom_permission) {

   } else if (defined_permission && !custom_permission) {
          await role.setPermissions({ [defined_permission]: enabled})
          interaction.reply(`Added the permission ${defined_permission} to the role <@&${role.id}>`)
          console.log(`✅ > ${interaction.user.username} added the permission ${defined_permission} to the role ${role.name}`)
            
   } else if (defined_permission && custom_permission) {

   } else {
          interaction.reply("Please input what permission you would like to edit")
   }
```

Error:

```
node:events:492
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: [object Object].
    at PermissionsBitField.resolve (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:172:11)
    at new BitField (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\BitField.js:33:38)
    at new PermissionsBitField (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\PermissionsBitField.js:12:1)
    at RoleManager.edit (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\RoleManager.js:203:68)
    at Role.edit (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Role.js:254:29)
    at Role.setPermissions (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\Role.js:333:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\src\index.js:277:24)
    at Client.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Development\Visual Studio Code Projects\GuildTweaker\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:395:10)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
```

Expectations:
If I were to use the command such as:
"/edit @definedrole4 true SEND_MESSAGES"
"/edit [ROLE] [bool] [PERMISSION]"

Answer (score 0):

[`Role.setPermissions()`](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Role?scrollTo=setPermissions) only accepts an array of [PermissionResolvable](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/main/typedef/PermissionResolvable).

```js
await role.setPermissions(['AddReactions', 'SendMessages']);
```

And to remove permissions:

```js
await role.setPermissions(0n);
```

In your code, you can do something like the below to handle removing and adding permissions to the role:

```js
const role = interaction.options.getRole('role');
const defined_permission = interaction.options.getString('defined-permission');
const enabled = interaction.options.getBoolean('enabled');

const permissions = role.permissions.toArray();

if (defined_permission) {
    if (enabled) {
        permissions.push(defined_permission);
    } else {
        permissions.splice(permissions.indexOf(defined_permission), 1);
    }
    await role.setPermissions(permissions);
}
```